# pip install erro

Tags: python, django, cmd, pip, operating-system

any time I use the "pip install" command on my terminal i get error, most times "ERROR:exception"[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqP8u.png)

Comment: Try updating pip by this code: `python -m pip install –upgrade pip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay what's happening there is your pip installer can't find any module because its out date by itself.So first update your pip installer with `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python` sorry but you didnt specify your OS. You can try after updating your installer.

Comment: i use a windows

Comment: Upgrade pip to the latest version using  ```py -m pip install --upgrade ```pip
then Install package using ```py -m pip install <package-name>``` maybe it can help

Comment: thank you! the update of pip installer using curl worked! i just installed Django